# Unable to insert a cross reference to a bookmark in specified cell in Word through with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, cross-reference

I am trying to cross reference a bookmark into the 2nd row of a column in a Word document, however, the bookmark keeps on being inserted in the first column. This is strange as I have selected the correct cell before inserting the cross reference.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or have any alternative methods of inserting a cross reference?

FYI the row selection seems to work fine each time.

```
NoOfTables = WordObject.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
For t = 1 To NoOfTables
    If WordObject.ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Title = "AsetRsetTbl" Then
        WordObject.ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Cell(2, 2).Select
        WordObject.Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", _
            ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, ReferenceItem:=BookMarkName & y, _
            InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, _
            SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
    End If
Next t
```

Comment: IMHO the [most important] first step in solving [or preventing] coding issues is attention to detail, in this case organization and neatness specifically. Being not-a-fan of following rules, I fought that for a long time but eventually had to concede: seemingly insignificant things like exact indentation and standardized line spacing go a long way in preventing & solving issues... I cleaned up your sample. It didn't solve the issue (yet) but it makes it easier (especially on others, who haven't seen your code before). "Organization is the key to success!" *(Sorry that's my rant for the day!)*

Comment: Check out "[mcve]" - I spent a few minutes trying to figure this out but it's impossible without more information. First, I have no clue as to the value of `WordObject`, `BookMarkName` or `y` at runtime, and I don't know how those or `NoOfTables` & `t` are declared, if at all. I can't assume that even likely unrelated things aren't causing the problem; obviously something (probably minor) isn't behaving properly.  Have you tried stepping through the code (with F8) and checking the values of each variable at each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. The key is how you specify where the cross-reference should go. I don't know "why", but when you select the entire cell Word decides the insertion point is in the previous cell. It probably has something to do with the cell structures in Word - only the people who wrote the underlying Word code know, for sure.

But, in any case, the trick is to do it as a user would. Usually, a user will click *in* a cell, so that the insertion point (cursor) is blinking.

Because, as with Excel, it's always better to *not* work with Selection, I've changed the code to use a `Range` object to target where the cross-reference goes. Whether you use `Range` or `Selection` - the key is to *collapse* the selection (like pressing the left or right arrow key on the keyboard).

I also changed to the code to make it more efficient and accurate, working with a `Document` object instead of `ActiveDocument`, which could change without your being aware of it.

```
Sub XRefInTable()
    Dim WordObject As word.Application
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim tbl As word.Table
    Dim rngCell As word.Range
    Dim t As Long, NoOfTables As Long

    Set WordObject = New Word.Application
    Set doc = WordObject.ActiveDocument
    NoOfTables = doc.Tables.Count
    For t = 1 To NoOfTables
        If doc.Tables(t).Title = "AsetRsetTbl" Then
            Set rngCell = doc.Tables(t).Cell(2, 2).Range
            rngCell.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            rngCell.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", _
                ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, ReferenceItem:=bookmarkname & y, _
                InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, _
                SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I have alot to learn it seems. Thank you for your detailed answer, and solving the issue completely. I now feel I need to go through my macros and switch out all the selection based code. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :-) If what you have works, no hurry to switch from Selection to Range - and there are a couple of things where Selection is better. But on the whole Range is more accurate, more reliable, less distracting for the eye and faster (since the screen doesn't need to update).